# Are MITM possible when using IP

Tags: go, security, ssl, networking

If I'm making TLS requests to an API server that I'm referencing by IP, are the kinds of MITM attacks that certificate validation prevents still possible?

Background info if it clarifies the question:  I'm making TLS requests to a REST API with a static IP that has no domain name associated with it.  To make this work in Go, I have to set the `InsecureSkipVerify: true,` at the Transport layer of my HTTP Client.  Does this make my requests less secure?
I would assume it does but I don't really know why.

Comment: "Does this make my requests less secure?" Yes. If you skip certificate verification the certificate won't be verified and you have no idea who you are talking to.

Comment: ... which means that, in particular, MITM attacks are now trivial. Note that there is no inherent reason why accessing the site by IP address cannot be just as secure as accessing by domain name, provided: the certificate is valid and has that IP address as one of its subject alternative names (SANs) and the authority who signed the certificate is trusted by the clients. However, not all CAs will sign a certificate that contains an IP address as one of its SANs.

Comment: Thank you for the clear answer. I wanted to be sure I wasn't unnecessarily asking too much from the API by requiring a signed endpoint to use.

Comment: you should expect the API provider to use a dns hostname.  It's really not anything to ask, in fact they *must* provide a hostname to get a valid Cert signed by any CA I've ever heard of.  Tell them to stop monkeying around and set up DNS - it's not hard.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @James noted the `IP` is an irrelevant component of a TLS handshake.

While the standard procedure is:

- dial hostname/port
- DNS lookup hostname to get IP
- TLS handshake w/ IP

  - reveals hostnames certificate identity
  - verify cert name matches hostname

Using `InsecureSkipVerify: true` skips the last step - and is generally only used during development/testing.

You can however use a *different* name, in this last step, for the certificate identity to match: leveraging the `ServerName` field in [tls.Config](https://pkg.go.dev/crypto/tls#Config):

```
tc = &tls.Config{
    ServerName: "myhostname", // certificate identity
    RootCAs:    rootca,
    // InsecureSkipVerify: true // <- avoid using this
}

d := tls.Dialer{
    Config: tc
}

conn, err := d.Dial("tcp", "127.0.0.1:8080")
```

Here we are dialing an IP address, performing a TLS handshake, but instead of the default behavior of comparing the host cert with `127.0.0.1`, it will instead verify it matches `myhostname`.

Comment: Thank you for that note.  I think I can actually use that to get around their issue.

Comment: Certificate verification consists of more than checking the host name, in fact the certification chain validation might be even more important than the host name check itself, since matching the host name means nothing of the CA isn’t trusted.

Comment: @JimB TLS only works with pre-established trust. The current Ubuntu image deliver 127 (!!!) CAs in its trust chain. Is that too many - probably! But that's a discussion outside the scope of this question. If one doesn't like deep trust chains - and have control over both ends of the pipe - then just create your own PKI.

Comment: All I’m saying is that validation consists of more than matching the host name. I can easily create an untrusted cert that matches the given host name. the entire validation process is important when considering what InsecureSkipVerify does.

Comment: @JimB yes, you can easily create a fake cert signed by your *own* rootCA - but one  cannot coerce others to trust that rootCA.

Comment: Actually @colm.anseo, there is a history of CAs happily signing CSRs for domains and addresses they shouldn't do. They're better these days than they were in the past, and the CAA DNS entry and the certificate transparency checks helps a bit, but still isn't perfect. https://ui.ctsearch.entrust.com/ui/ctsearchui